# Enable Authorize button in Swagger

Tags: security, jax-rs, cxf, swagger

I want to enable api_key security definition in my Swagger client/documentation.

I use swagger-ui-2.2.10.

I use JAX-RS with CXF, and **Swagger2Feature with a bean.xml configuration**.

I want to activate my http,https schemes too.

Here is an example what I want to get:
[authorize button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/quoao.jpg) and
[authorization with api key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kvDwF.jpg)

I am not sure if I can do that wit Swagger annotations like:

```
authorizations = {@Authorization(value="api_key")}
```

or

```
@ApiKeyAuthDefinition(name="Authorization", description="X-API-Key", in=ApiKeyLocation.HEADER, key = "")
```

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45034082/add-securityschemedefinition-to-swagger2features-in-cxf, just add the securityDefinitions as given in the answer and it will work.