# Add SecuritySchemeDefinition to Swagger2Features in CXF

Tags: security, cxf, swagger

I want to enable authorize button in my Swagger v2 API REST Documentation.

How can I define api_key security with Swagger2Features?

Comment: Please review the following and update your question according:

https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

```
  swagger2Feature.setSecurityDefinitions(
     Collections.singletonMap("apiKeySecurity", new io.swagger.models.auth.ApiKeyAuthDefinition()));
```

Make sure to use the latest CXF version as there were some bugfixes in this area.

Comment: It can be made by property tag in the beans.xml spring file?

Comment: it can be made by swagger annotations in my service class?

Comment: See http://cxf.apache.org/docs/swagger2feature.html for different possibilities of configuring it.